# How to check if predicate is always true or always false

Tags: prolog

How can I check that a predicate will be true no matter what a certain variable is, given the other variable? Or alternatively, that no matter what the one variable is it will fail?

I am trying to make a predicate taut/1 and a predicate unsat/1
taut(F) should be true if F is a tautology and unsat(F) should be true if there are no solutions to F.

I have a predicate sat/1 that will succeed (and give the solutions) if there are solutions to the expression and fail if there are none. But it uses an uninstantiated variable, so I can't use not/1 to make unsat/1 with it.

I know that if I can define either one of these two, I can define the other in terms of it (as I can negate the expression F with some of the rest of my program).

How I made the sat/1:

```
sat(F) :- solve(F,_).
```

This doesn't work:

```
unsat(F) :- not(sat(F)).
```

How I can define unsat/1 and taut/1 in terms of each other (this should work given the rest of my program) (I will only use one of these, depending on which I can define in terms of sat/1 or solve/2):

```
unsat(F) :- taut(neg(F)).

taut(F) :- unsat(neg(F)).
```

solve/2 behaves such that it will answer true if both variables are instantiated and that the second is a valid valuation (a list of the terms that must be true) of the expression in the first.

Ie: `solve(p(1),[1]).` gives `true`

If the second variable is uninstantiated, it will find all viable valuations (I have checked that this works) or say no if there are none.

Ie: `solve(p(1),V).`gives `V=[1]; yes` and `solve(and(p(1),neg(p(1)),V).` gives `no`

How can I use either sat/1 or solve/2 to define either taut/1 or unsat/1?

Example of how I would like the taut/1 and unsat/1 to work:

```
| ?- taut(or(p(1),neg(p(1)))).

yes
| ?- unsat(and(p(1),neg(p(1)))).

yes
| ?-
```

(I use GNU-Prolog, in case that makes any difference.)

Comment: SICStus and SWI offer a CLP(B) solver exactly for this purpose.

Comment: I might be wrong, but your `solve` sounds exactly like `bagof/3` and `setof/3`: those succeed if there are any solutions, and collect the solutions, and fail if there are no solutions. I might be wrong but simply using `\+` on `bagof` and `setof` should give you the opposite. If you provided the full code of at least a very simple example it would be easier to know what you are asking.

Comment: @Boris What sort of sorcery is this? It works with `\+` (but it doesn't with `not`).
Post that as an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: @false But I'm confined to GNU-prolog and using a ready-made one would defeat the purpose of the assignment ;)

Comment: I would have liked to write an answer, but I had trouble reconstructing an example given your question. Can you show a minimal example?

Comment: PS: I am not even sure if GNU-Prolog has `not`, anyway `not/1` seems to be deprecated for `\+/1` in the Prolog implementation I am familiar with.

Comment: *How can I check that a predicate will be true no matter what a certain variable is, given the other variable? Or alternatively, that no matter what the one variable is it will fail?* - I believe it is a generally undecidable problem as it is reducible to the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have the feeling this is a problem with OP's wording, I don't think it is as complex as that. As it stands, I am still not sure what is the actual aim of their code

Comment: @EugeneSh. That is, I still think that OP is describing `bagof/3` and `setof/3` and their negation.

Comment: @Boris OK, I am having a bit of difficulty (and laziness) to parse the whole description, so answered the titled question only. Perhaps it is not reflecting the actual problem..

Comment: @EugeneSh. You are definitively making this more complex than it needs to be, this is for instantiated logical expressions that may or may not be tautologies or unsatisfiable. I'm not sure how else to word it though.

Comment: @Boris I know `not` is deprecated, but my lecturer taught us to use it when needing that functionality, so I thought I'd use it. But I now have a working version with `unsat(F) :- \+(sat(F)).`